# How to create zend framework project in a joomla subdirectory?

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, joomla

I have my joomla in http://project/  and now I want to have http://project/zf-project/
What httaccess should I use? And what changes in the code?

Comment: Do you want to use ZF inside your Joomla? I very much hope this is a private project... otherwise, don't do it because you're very likely to create a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: these are two seperate projects. it will be no problems with mainentance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by

1. Not changing the ZF `.htaccess`
2. Putting my ZF public files inside `/public/zf-project` instead of `/public` this includes putting the ZF `.htaccess` file in `/public/zf-project`

Doing this worked fine for me without having to change anything else. Have you tried this?

EDIT

You could try adding to your Joomla `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteRule ^(zf-project) - [L]
```

After the line which reads

```
 RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Something's wrong. 1. It always points to index 2. no css/js files work. Maybe my apache vhost config or joomla htaccess are causing it?

Comment: Post Joomla's .htaccess file. There is something wrong somewhere, because ZF should work like this out of the box.

Comment: You may have to amend Joomla's htaccess to exclude your ZF project folder from its redirecting

Comment: That's not joomla's issue. It also doesn't work in other domains.

Comment: That's not joomla's issue. It also doesn't work in other domains. 
Now I looked at your structure. I put my public contents in http://domain/zfproject/ instead of http://domain/zfproject/public/ Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: It works in my development env except for public css/js files

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following .htaccess. It will work in subdirectories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Remember that you must apply baseUrl to your links, css files etc. This is necessary to include the sub-directory as a prefix to your urls.

Some of the classes in ZF already does that like the Url view helper.

Comment: I forgot to mention that http://project/zf-project/ should point to public directory. I already know the standard zf httaccess file, thanks.

Comment: You were right with regard to baseUrl. Thanks
However it seem it canno be set but must be applied to each file.